# No state error in C++ 11 futures/promises

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I am a bit confused about the behavior of futures/promises in C++.

The code is the following

```cpp
 std::future<std::string> method() {
        std::promise<std::string> pr;
        std::future<std::string> ft = pr.get_future();

        std::thread t(                   
            [](std::promise<std::string> p)  
            {                      
                p.set_value("z");  
            },                     
            std::move(pr)          
        );                       
        t.detach();                    

        return std::move(ft);          
 }
```

When I run the code, there is an exception `__throw_future_error((int)future_errc::no_state);` thrown at `std::future<std::string> ft = pr.get_future();`

Any idea why is this happening ?

EDIT:

So, I have a minimal example that showcases the problem. Coliru (with g++ 4.8 and a bit newer stdlib) somehow seems to run it fine, but when it comes to my workstation it fails.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/711e182594cbe7d3

I am compiling with

```
# gcc 4.7.3
g++ -g -std=c++11 -lpthread t.cpp -o t
```

and

```
# clang 3.2.1
clang++ -g -std=c++11 -lpthread t.cpp -o t
```

libstdc++ version is 3.4.17

Workstation is a Linux Mint 15

Comment: Which compiler are you using? In case of gcc/clang did you compile with -pthread? The code looks fine and it works for me (gcc-4.8, gcc-4.9 snapshot, some svn clang 3.3).

Comment: Clang, compiled with -lpthread -std=c++11. Threading actually works in the program as I have two other threads running.

Comment: [No problem compiling with clang at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa2096535a92116d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug.  The default constructor of `promise` is specified to construct a shared state for the `promise`.  The `future` returned from `pr.get_future()` should refer to that shared state.

Is `-stdlib=libc++` an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. -stdlib=libc++ gives <stdheader> file not found. I guess I'll have to check my stdlib version and come back with some version numbers.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I've updated gcc (to 4.8), the stdlib and clang (to 3.3) and it works. Thank you :)